# Объясните про fork в ОС

Tags: linux

Не могу понять почему fork() работает именно так. Вот отрывок из книги Таненбаума "Современные ОС"

> В UNIX существует только один системный вызов для создания нового
>   процесса — fork. Этот вызов создает точную копию вызывающего процесса.
>   После выполнения системного вызова fork два процесса, родительский и
>   дочерний, имеют единый образ памяти, единые строки описания
>   конфигурации и одни и те же открытые файлы. И больше ничего. Обычно
>   после этого дочерний процесс изменяет образ памяти и запускает новую
>   программу, выполняя системный вызов execve или ему подобный. Например,
>   когда пользователь набирает в оболочке команду sort, оболочка создает
>   ответвляющийся дочерний процесс, в котором и выполняется команда sort.
>   **Смысл этого двухступенчатого процесса заключается в том, чтобы позволить дочернему процессу управлять его файловыми дескрипторами
>   после разветвления, но перед выполнением execve с целью выполнения
>   перенаправления стандартного ввода, стандартного вывода и стандартного
>   вывода сообщений об ошибках.**

Не понимаю почему если мы вызываем команду sort, нельзя просто выполнить программу sort(), а нужно создавать копию этой программы

Comment: почти о том же самом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816388/178576

Comment: А что такое, в вашем представлении, "просто выполнить программу"?

Comment: Потому что **небходимо вернуться** в командную оболочку, иначе произойдёт *замещение* оболочки одиночным вызовом другой команды. Поведите эксперимент, вместо запуска *sort*, выполните *exec sort*. Доложите нам о результате.

Answer (score 3):

> почему если мы вызываем команду sort, нельзя просто выполнить программу sort(), а нужно создавать копию этой программы

Потому что после отработки вызванной программы (`sort`), текущей программе наверняка надо сделать **ещё хоть что-нибудь** полезное.

А если она не выполнит сначала `fork()`, то вызовом `execve()` она перезапишет (вызываемой программой) **саму себя**.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вопрос немного о другом: типа, зачем создавать копию текущего процесса и запускать в нём sort, если теоретически можно сразу создать новый процесс с sort'ом внутри без всяких копий (как я понимаю, именно это и происходит в Windows, в отличие от юниксов)

Comment: @andreymal, да, возможно, автор недопонимает разницу между «загрузить библитотеку в адресное пространство процесса» и «загрузить программу поверх текущего процесса». // p.s. а разница в старте нового процесса в unix и ms/windows неплохо изложена по ссылке, которую я привёл в комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: Ну, автор про библиотеки абсолютно ничего не говорил (лишь отдалённо намекают скобочки после sort), но тоже вариант

Comment: Вы о чём вообще, господа?! Очевидно же, что ветвление необходимо, чтобы иметь возможность вернуться в командную оболочку. Иначе смысл командной оболочки теряется.

Answer (score -1):

Как минимум потому, что глючный "ребенок" (программа, загружаемая и выполняемая прямо в процессе родителя) может уронить, блокировать, писать в память и вообще всячески мешать родительской программе. Это же будет коммунальная квартира, где в случае возгорания матраца Васи-алкоголика пострадают все

Comment: А зачем ребенку отдавать свою память и хэндлы? Windows же позволяет запускать дочерние процессы без клонирования родителя

Comment: А как память программа может что-то уронить, если ей выделяется область памяти, которая не пересекается с другими программами?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, копия же, поломать родителя уже не получится. А хэндлы шарить бывает полезно.

Comment: @ЮрийКот, если запуск новой программы будет происходить внутри того же процесса, то память будет общей. Одна из причин создания нового процесса - это его изоляция.

Comment: Так не давать ничего и копия не нужна. То, что хэндлы полезно шарить - не спорю. Но, обычно из нескольких сотен хендлов родителя, ребенку нужен десяток, максимум. А то и 2-3. Так, что проще расшарить десяток конкретных хэндлов, чем копировать (даже если copy-on-write) всю память

Comment: @free_ze, вы, видимо, не очень понимаете, как там на самом деле всё устроено. В частности разницу между потоками и процессами.

Comment: @0andriy, а вы ясность внести сможете или просто гадаете по комментариям?