# В чем реальный, прикладной смысл применения функции fork и execve?

Tags: linux, c

//Читаю книгу по программированию в Linux. Уперся в тему многозадачности, не понимаю в чем суть применения данных функций. По большому счету смысл мне понятен(глобально), но, при непосредственном исследовании кода не особо..

//Есть задание: Выполнить программу вывода из файла в файл с помощью функции fork. Сам синтаксис я вывожу, например, самая простая программа с использование fork() :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    int main (void)
{
    fork ();
    printf ("Hello World\n");
    sleep (15);  
    return 0;
}
```

//Это все понятно.И результат мне ясен: создание 2 процессов(родительского и дочернего).Но зачем создавать 2 одинаковых процесса и в дальнейшем уже изменять полученный, когда можно создать без функции fork() новый процесс без клонирования.

1)Концепция развилки: fork() Для порождения нового процесса предназначен системный вызов fork() Системный вызов fork() порождает процесс методом "клонирования". Это значит,
что новый процесс является точной копией своего родителя и выполняет ту же са-
мую программу.

2)Системный вызов execve() загружает в процесс другую программу и передает ей
безвозвратное управление.

Comment: Попробуйте какую-нибудь другую книгу. Это дзен -). Вообще, чтобы постичь \*nix нужно понять всего 7 системных вызовов -- open, close, read, write, fork, exit и exec

Comment: для связки слов в предложении: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816388/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/852629/178576)

Comment: Да, спасибо , писал этот вопрос до того, как наткнулся на подобные здесь на сайте.В принципе вопрос исчерпан

Comment: Эта программа некорректная - результат fork игнорируется.

Answer (score 2):

В линуксе есть только один официальный способ создать новый процесс - сделать fork, и все. Но так как два одинаковые процессы обычно не нужны, то в одном из них выполняется `exec*` функция, для замены программы нужной.

С одной стороны это странно, но с другой - гибко - можно передать запускаемой программе практически что угодно - параметры, файловые дескрипторы, права доступа на файлы и так далее. К примеру, так работает апач. Есть один процесс с "большими правами", он слушает 80/443 порт (обычный процесс этого так просто не может делать), когда появляется соединение, он форкает себя, понижает права и отдает и продолжает обработку. Если процесс попытается сделать что то плохое (файлы системные потрогать) - у него не получится. Если упадет - ну ничего плохого тоже не произойдет.

Comment: Спасибо.Нашел похожий вопрос по ссылке.Там он неплохо разъясняется. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816388/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-posix-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-fork-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8e